# How can I make my html anchor tag link to a random html file in the same folder as it

Tags: html

I want the user to be directed to a random .html page inside the same folder when they click a button.  So if index.html, 1.html and 2.html are all in the same folder and the user clicks the button on index.html it will randomly choose either of the other 2 pages.  Thanks.

Comment: set the href attribute of `<a>` by javascript by generating random number and taking decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution can be attained using Javascript & PHP.
The logic behind the solution is:

1) We are scanning ([scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)) the entire folder for all the files present in the folder.{*Only possible in PHP and not in Javascript*}

2) We are counting the number of files present in the folder.

3) From the array[index] we are selecting a random number.

4) We are checking that the random file is not the current file (So that random file is not index.html and can be 1.html, 2.html, 3.html, 4.html)

**Javascipt Solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=['index.html', '1.html', '2.html'];
var total_no_files = a.length;
var random_no = Math.floor((Math.random() * total_no_files) + 0);

var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

if(filename != a[random_no]){ document.write('<a href="' + a[random_no] + '">random Link</a>'); }
</script>
```

**PHP Solution**

```
<?php
$dir = "../Folder/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);

// $a[0]=. $a[1]=..
$total_no_files = count($a)-2;

// We should start from array[2] and go upto the end
$random_no = rand(2, $total_no_files+1);

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$end = end((explode('/', $url)));

if($end != $a[$random_no]){ ?><a href="<?php echo $a[$random_no]; ?>">Random Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @War10ck: I have added the Javascript solution as well keeping the logic same as PHP

Answer (score 0):

You'd either a server side language or JavaScript to do that.

For JS:

```
<a href="javascript:" id="random">some text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var element = document.getElementByID('random');
  var files = ['1.html','2.html'];
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length);
  element =  element.setAttribute("href",files[index]);
</script>
```

(not tested)

For PHP server side:

```
<?php
  $files = array('1.html','2.html');
  $index = mt_rand(0,count($files));
  $link = $files[$index];
?>
<a href="<?php echo($link) ?>">some text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as you said that 1.html and 2.html exist in the same directory, you could use a simple JavaScript solution to randomly browse to either page like so:

```
function RandomHREF() {
        randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1
        window.location= randnum + ".html"
    }
```

Comment: Please not only paste code, but explain your choice. Perhaps you can also mention the issue that using this solution will most likely generate a link to a non-existent file if the file does not exist on disk.